# Error :- Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemVersion

Tags: 2013, development, powershell, versioning, issue-tracking

I am working on an `Issue tracking list` inside SharePoint team site and i need to modify the **"Editor"** & **"Modified"** fields for an existing item's version comment:-

[image]

so i wrote the following power-shell script, to get the first comment of an item and update its fields (Editor & Modified fields):-

```
#set the web url and the list name to work upon
$url = "http://***/Customer Sites/customerA/"
$listName = "Action"
$fileName = "12312312"
 
#Get the appropriate list from the web
$web = get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.lists[$listName]
 
#Get the file using the filename
$item = $list.Items | ? {$_.Title -eq $fileName}
$versions = $item.versions 
$version = $versions[0];

 
#Set the created by values
$userLogin = "a***\m***"
$dateToStore = Get-Date "10/03/2015 10:15:20"
$dateToStore2 = Get-Date "12/03/2015 23:15:20"
 
$user = Get-SPUser -Web $web | ? {$_.userlogin -eq $userLogin}
$userString = "{0};#{1}" -f $user.ID, $user.UserLogin.Tostring()
 
 
#Sets the created by field

 
#Set the modified by values
$version["Editor"] = $userString
$version["Modified"] = $dateToStore2
 
 
#Store changes without overwriting the existing Modified details.
$item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

but i got the following exception on `$version["Editor"] = $userString` &   `$version["Modified"] = $dateToStore2` statments:-

> Unable to index into an object of type
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemVersion.

here is a screenshot of my power-shell window with the exception that i got:-

[image]

so can anyone advice how i can edit these 2 fields for an item comment ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the field value of a field in a particular item version using $version.item["Field Display name"] but I think it is a read only property and you cant set it via code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversion_members.aspx

Comment: Yes seems i can not update them as they are read-only, so is there a way to create new version for an item using powershell and pass these info to it ; created date, create by + comment text ? i need this as i am merging multiple lists inside one list, and to do so i need to preserve the original item versions info, so i want to create these versions on the new list to match the old list info ?